# Storing and retrieving images with MVC and Sql Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, image

I am designing an prototyping an app the needs to store images, similar to facebook. This will be a public facing site and I am not sure how many users I will end up with but what I am looking for is a way to efficiently retrieve them.

So far I am thinking of storing them in SQL Server varbinary columns. Is this a good idea? I have the upload code and the storage code for that. My concern is retrieving them. I can retireve and build the image tag on the fly but I am worried about having to hit the database for each one.

I have been thinking about getting all images for a user and caching them in the asp.net cache for 10 to 30 seconds. I have never had to do something like this so I would be interested in hearing a few different approaches. Obviously the images can vary in size and I was thinking about defining a size limit, but I haven't gotten that far yet.

Thanks for your help.
Paul Speranza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that IIS already does quite a good job at caching static content so I would probably just save the images on disk and save information about their placement in the DB.

Comment: I agree. Store the Uri in the db and the files on disk. If your website grows then the physical files can be moved to a SAN.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Since I have never used a SAN, my next question is that even though using a SAN would have the files on another device, would it be more efficient than going to a database?

Answer (score 2):

Do not store images in your database.  It will hurt the performance of both your database and your web site.

The only exception is if you're going to use SQL 2008's `FILESTREAM` type, which basically uses the file system to store the files and just keeps a reference to it in the DB.

Definitely don't store raw image data in a `varbinary` column.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could re-size your images prior to putting them in sql server.
Also, you could make a http handler that retrieves images from sql server, but I would set the cache to be like a minute or two, not less. They don't change that much.

```
context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10));
```

Another option is to store on the file server, you can write these files anywhere IIS has permissions, and store the file "url" like "C:\images\test.jpg" in the database. But then you have to write something to delete the file when the record is removed.